# Did Stalin kill all Soviet officers involved in the Winter War?

Tags: world-war-two, soviet-union, stalin, finland

Did Stalin kill all of the Soviet officers involved in the Winter War, when it ended?

A documentary called "[Warlords: Hitler vs Stalin](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=E2zrqzvtWio)" made this claim, but Wikipedia doesn't seem to mention this.

---

Actual quote from the film:

> Finally, the Finns were beaten, but not before killing 125,000 Russian soldiers. Stalin sent in his political komissars to shoot the Soviet commanders, but the real fault was his own.

Since there was no reference to any specific commanders, the sentence implies some punitive systematic killing of Soviet commanders.

Comment: I don't think any movie that made such an absurd claim could be called "documentary".

Comment: @IMil - Since "mockumentaries" are so universally godawful, my vote is that we simply pretend they don't exist and repurpose the word for crappy HistoryChannel shows.

Comment: This question originally said "... kill all Soviet officers..." and both answers were posted on the basis of that phrasing. The edit to "... kill the Soviet officers..." essentially invalidates both answers so I've submitted an edit to revert that. MaxB, please don't edit your question in a way that invalidates answers that have already been posted. If you want to ask a more nuanced question, please post a new question, and please make it less vague than "... kill the officers..." Some of them? Most of them? Almost all of them?

Comment: I would say that there is a disconnect between the question and the source, i.e. "Soviet Commanders" != "all soviet officers".

Comment: @T.E.D. Alternatively, "knockumentary" (a knock-off of reality), "badumentary" (a metaphorically autological neologism) and "documadeupentary" (just rolls off the tongue, doesn't it?).

Comment: @wizzwizz4 - How about "Derpumentary"?

Comment: Silly me, we apparently already have [Schlockumentary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/schlockumentary)

Comment: My grandfather was an officer in Winter War and he was not executed or otherwise punished. He survived WWII and died in 1986.

Answer (score 74, accepted):

[Wikipedia article on the Winter War](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Winter_War)

The 3 top Soviet officers (apart from Stalin):

- [Kliment Voroshilov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kliment_Voroshilov): died 2 December 1969.
- [Semyon Timoshenko](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semyon_Timoshenko): died 31 March 1970.
- [Kirill Meretskov](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kirill_Meretskov): died 30 December 1968.

Since Stalin died 5 March 1953, it is rather obvious that there were officers (at least three of them!) involved in the Winter War who were not executed (Voroshilov was sacked from his post, though).

The claim is false.

Comment: Is it suspicious that all three of these guys died with about 2 years of eachother?

Comment: @DarrelHoffman no

Comment: @DarrelHoffman: They died at ages 71, 75, 88. So, not really suspicious.

Comment: Yeah but it's hard to know who survived and didn't and their exact dates of death. USSR has a tendency to rewrite history. During the Great Purge, many of the top officers were purged. TWO out of FIVE top generals for example. Stalin even apparently refused carpets so he can hear assassins sneaking up. I mean some people even think Stalin was murdered.

Answer (score 31):

Certainly not "all officers", [but some](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/44th_Rifle_Division_(Soviet_Union)):

> According to Robert Edwards, the [44th] division's Commander A. Vinogradev
>   managed to escape, but later, on the orders of Stalin's emissary, Lev
>   Mekhlis, he was shot for incompetence following a sham trial. [...]
>
> Other records suggest that Commander (kombrig) Alexei Vinogradov was
>   sentenced in January 1940 to the Highest Degree of Punishment (VMN) by
>   the Military Tribunal of the 9th Army along with his chief of
>   staff Onufri Volkov. On January 11 he was publicly executed in front
>   of [the] formation.

Answer (score 2):

The head commander, Meretskov, was promoted after the winter war, in spite of all his inability. So, definitely, the answer is "no".